# Making Just One POST Request When Multiple Values Are Received in Angular App

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, post

In my Angular app I have a situation where I am passing user-selected filter values from one component to another via event emitters. The problem is, rather than sending out one POST request with those filter values, currently it's sending out a POST request FOR EACH value that's emitted/received. What I need to do is figure out how to collect those values, and then send just one POST request.

In the view of my receiving component I am taking those emitted event values, and passing them into an onFiltersReceived() function, like so:

```
<data-view [records]="records"
    (sendLocation)="onFilterReceived($event, type = 'location')"
    (sendZipcode)="onFilterReceived($event, type = 'zipcode')"
    (sendFirstName)="onFilterReceived($event, type = 'firstName')"
    (sendLastName)="onFilterReceived($event, type = 'lastName')"
    (sendLanguage)="onFilterReceived($event, type = 'language')"
    (sendBranch)="onFilterReceived($event, type = 'branch')">
</data-view>
```

I then send out an API request to filter according to those passed in filter values, like this:

```
public onFilterReceived(value, type) {
    let selections = this.filtersService.processByTypes(value, type);

    let fn = resRecordsData => {
        this.records = resRecordsData;
        let data = resRecordsData.data;
    };

     this.filtersService.getByFilters(
        this.page - 1, this.pagesize, this.language = selections.language, this.location = selections.location,
        this.zipcode = selections.zipcode, this.firstName = selections.firstName, this.lastName = selections.lastName,
        this.branch = selections.branch, fn);
}
```

The "filtersService" service layer functions referenced here look like this. First, the function that handles the incoming filters:

```
filters = { language: [], location: [], zipcode: [], firstName: [], lastName: [], branch: [] };

public processByTypes(value, type) {
  if (value && type) { this.filters[type] = value; }
  return this.filters;
}
```

And then the API POST request that's sent out over the wire:

```
public getByFilters(page, pagesize, language?, location?, zipcode?, firstName?, lastName?, branch?, fn?: any)
{
    return this.apiService.post({
        req: this.strReq, reqArgs: { page, pagesize, language, location, zipcode, firstName, lastName, branch }, callback: fn });
}
```

Again, as I say, this works - but ineficciently, because the POST request fires off FOR EACH of the emitted values taken in via event emitters by the onFilterReceived() function, even if the details of the request haven't changed. How can I change this to make just one POST request - rather than having it fire every time an input is received?

I tried making onFilterReceived() and async function, and awaiting on the "selections", like this:

```
public async onFilterReceived(value, type) {
    let selections = await this.filtersService.processByTypes(value, type);
    // other stuff
```

... But of course the issue here is that the rest of the steps in the function (including the API POST request) will fire, without waiting on "selections" to resolve. How can I address this so I'm making just one POST request?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally clear on your design here, but is waiting for some time after you detect a change before refiltering the dataset an option?

This could be accomplished via a Debounce (https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function), and is the traditional way of handling filters over a POST request where you want to refilter on changes to the input.

Essentially you are just ratelimiting your function call, such that once the first filter POST happens you have a window where you can make changes without triggering another POST.

Comment: This does look like it gets at what I'm trying to accomplish. Will explore further. Thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help ^_^

Comment: Actually, after running this, and it not working, I realized it's an "observable". But, because of that, I'm thinking I should be able to chain on an operator switchMap to achieve the same effect. Looking into this now.

Comment: Observable vs. Promise shouldn't matter much. It seems like your problem is just making a decision as to what the trigger for an update should be, and how often the update should be triggered. If you want to update on any change to any property, you need to rate limit updates. Otherwise, you need to only trigger updates on changes to all properties (or some other scheme).

Comment: I agree. But because this is Angular, and this is an observable, I'm thinking I should be able to use something like `switchMap` to accomplish this.

Comment: Have you had any success with the switchMap?